# Links in PHP that change a query in another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, e-commerce

I have a basic e-commerce site I'm making for University.

I have some code that selects all items from the MySQL database and displays them in a nice grid.

I have another page that lists all the sellers as links - again taken from the database.

What I'd like to do is make it so when I click on an artist's name, it displays only their items.

I know I just have to do a MySQL query using a WHERE statement to select that person - my issue is the PHP code that'll take the name from the list, and how to translate that to execute a query.

Should I wrap the PHP that has all the items displayed in a function and pass in a parameter that defaults to null, and if not null, do a search?

The way I'm currently doing it is writing a PHP script that contains the items to display, and using include_once("scriptName.php"); in the HTML to display it where I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is create an `artist` column in the `items` table, and then show all `items` with/from that `artist`.

```
$artist = 'jimbo';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM itemsforsale WHERE artist=:artist"; #LIMIT 1
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt -> bindValue(':artist', $artist, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt -> execute(); 
  while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    return $result; //hey, Jimbo's stuff from database in an assoc array!
  }
```

**this assumes `itemsforsale` is the table in the database housing the items*